# Whether a half bridge SMPS based on MOSFET or another one based on BJT will generate more switching noise at the output?

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, bjt, noise, emi-filtering

Whether a half bridge SMPS based on MOSFET or another one based on BJT will generate more switching noise at the output?, if other parameters such as output voltage, current, type of transformer core, switching frequency,  etc remains the same. I'm only asking how the type of switching device affects noise, let's assume I drive the MOSFET/BJT via transformer, while MOSFET driving maybe simple and straightforward, BJT drive circuit may have a baker clamp.

Comment: The amount of switching noise doesn't **only** depend on the type of transistor that is used as a switching element. I suggest that you study a book about SMPS design and learn what influences switching noise.

Comment: I second what @Bimpelrekkie says. Plus, instead of the switching element, the switching **technique** is more important.

Comment: That's why I added the second sentence, imagine all the other parameters stay the same, I'm only asking how the type of switching device affects noise, let's assume I drive the MOSFET/BJT via transformer, while MOSFET driving maybe simple and straightforward, BJT drive circuit has a baker clamp.

Comment: Do you mean input or output noise? $$$$Are you also aware that those questions you have previously raised that have a satisfactory answer should be closed-down by selecting the most appropriate answer and formally accepting it. This is what is expected from you for the benefit of getting good answers. I would think about this first.

Comment: Yes, output noise.

@Andyaka I have accepted the appropriate answers for my previous questions.

Comment: This question is tricky to decide upon and I would definitely turn to using a simulation tool for looking into the nuances. But the bigger issue is comparing apples with apples so, if you had two near-identical circuits where one used a BJT and the other used a MOSFET maybe that would make it easier.